How do I make a compose dialog respect a fold device navigation bar?
I have the following simple code that draws a blue dialog with a yellow square:
setContent {

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
        ) {
            Text("Hello")
        }

        Dialog(
            onDismissRequest = {},
            properties = DialogProperties(
                dismissOnBackPress = false,
                dismissOnClickOutside = false,
                usePlatformDefaultWidth = false,
            ),
        ) {

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .navigationBarsPadding()
                    .background(Color.Blue),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
            ) {

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(100.dp)
                        .background(Color.Yellow)
                ) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


However, if I modify the dialog's usePlatformDefaultWidth to false, I get a Dialog which hides beneath the navigation bar:

How can I make the dialog respect the navigation bar insets/paddings when usePlatformDefaultWidth is set to false? Note how the Column inside the Dialog is calling .navigationBarsPadding(), to no effect. Also, I've tried to use WindowInsets inside the dialog and log its values but everything is zero, as if the Dialog is oblivious to the navigation bar, so I don't know how I can compensate this.

Did you find a solution for this? I am facing exactly the same issue in Android tablet emulators. Phone is working correctly.

@RaviRaj No solution found so far.

I don't have a real Tablet device to test this, did you get a chance to test on it and does the issue persist? If so how did you solve it?

It's a bug in the compose library: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/246909281
